# lex parser to programs written in pascal

Tags: c, lex

I have a problem with writing Pascal analyzer using Lex, which after parsing should print to stdout information about the correct / incorrect code structure and a summary containing the number of rows of the program, the number of variables used, the number used in an if, while, repeat, etc.

I do not know how to go about it.

Comment: Since you can put arbitrary code after each regular expression, it's hard to guess where your problem might be without seeing what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this short example:

```
  "{"           { return(LCURLY);       }
  "}"           { return(RCURLY);       }
  ","           { return(COMMA);        }
  ":"           { return(COLON);        }
  \.            { return(DOT);          }
  "+"           { return(PLUS);         }
  "-"           { return(MINUS);        }
  "*"           { return(MULTIPLY);     }
  "/"           { return(DIVIDE);       }
```

Whenever a certain regex patter will match, the action on the right will happen. Just add a printf() to report that a correct token was detected.

```
"/"         { printf("Token %s \n", yytext);return(DIVIDE);     }
```

The last line should be:

```
 .          { printf("Error not recognized: %s\n", yytext);
```

The last line of course means any incorrect token -> any token that I didn't write a regex to match.